# using dynamic keyword when parse JSON

Tags: c#, json, dynamic

I'm newbie to using the `dynamic` keyword in C#. It seems simple enough, but I can't seem to use it effectively.

I see this example from Facebook:

```
var client = new FacebookClient();
dynamic me = client.Get("totten");
string firstname = me.first_name;
```

it works fine, but if you look at `me` in a debugger, then you can see that `client.Get()` returns simple JSON. The same it's said in Facebook documentation:

> The result of this request is a dynamic object containing various
>   properties such as first_name, last_name, user name, etc. You can see
>   the values of this request by browsing to
>   http://graph.facebook.com/totten in your web browser. The JSON result
>   is shown below.

I want to do the same dodge with returned JSON from Foursquare:

```
private static string GetReturnedUrlFromHttp(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    webRequest.Timeout = 10000;
    webRequest.Method = "GET";
    WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();

    string responseStr = String.Empty;

    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        var r = new StreamReader(stream);
        responseStr = r.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return responseStr;
}

public static void FillDataFromFoursquareUsingDynamic()
{
    string foursquare_url_detail = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4b80718df964a520e57230e3?locale=en&client_id=XXX&client_secret=YYY&v=10102013";
    dynamic responseStr = GetReturnedUrlFromHttp(foursquare_url_detail);
    var response = responseStr.response;
}
```

I got the following error:

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'response'

Why am I getting this error and is it possible to 'parse' any JSON string like in Facebook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FacebookClient.Get` doesn't really return the JSON *string*. Instead it parses the string into a dynamic object with properties matching the names of the values in the JSON string.

Using `dynamic` doesn't magically turn a string into an object with the properties defined in the string. Instead, you need to first parse the string with the help of a JSON library like JSON.NET.